# Import csv into sqlite with autoincrementing primary key

Tags: database, csv, sqlite

I am trying to create a table in sqlite that takes data from a csv file and adds an autoincrementing primary key to the first column.
Here is the table I am trying to insert data into:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Allegiance;
CREATE TABLE Allegiance (
  AllegianceID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  CharacterID INTEGER,
  Title TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (CharacterID) REFERENCES Characters(CharacterID));
```

Here is the data in the .csv file

```
, 3, King of the North
, 14, King of the Andals and the First Men
, 15, Lord of Dragonstone
, 26, Khaleesi
, 35, Lord Reaper of Pyke
```

This is the error I recieve:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> import allegiances.csv Allegiance;
Error: datatype mismatch
```

I receive the same error if I have "null" before the first comma in each line.
When I add random numbers before the first comma in each line, I do not get any errors. However, the actual dataset I need to work with may be much larger and therefore, I can't simply manually add in a unique primary key for each entry. I'd really appreciate some help with this

Comment: If you are using third party programs, you may have the option to set the text that represent the NULL value in your csv file. SQLiteStudio is one of those programs.

Comment: @VassilisGr What do you mean by the text that represent the NULL value?

Comment: @pouya, if you have a csv file that a row is like `pouya, 26, NULL`, you can set that the NULL value in your csv file is represented by "NULL" string. In case of `pouya, 26,,` you would set NULL is "" (empty string). Or `pouya, 26, 0` the NULL is "0" in the csv file!

Comment: @VassilisGr so how SQLiteStudio or any other software defines a NULL value in a csv file?

Comment: @pouya, is a matter of *string to db specific* and *db specific to string*, where string is the null string representation and it can be "NULL", or empty string as I mentioned. It should be a user preference in such apps. That's all.

Comment: @VassilisGr thank you for that tip, I had to specify NULL explicitly in SQLite Studio even though it was already set to ;;

Answer (score 38, accepted):

An empty field in a CSV file is just an empty string, which is not valid for an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column.

Import into a temporary table without that column, then copy the data over with:

```
INSERT INTO Allegiance(CharacterID, Title) SELECT * FROM TempTable;
```

Comment: I got an error with this solution, I had to add a null field in the SELECT list INSERT INTO Allegiance(CharacterID, Title) SELECT NULL,Title FROM TempTable;

Comment: THANKS, Giorgio. That worked for mismatch columns sizes. I had 33 columns in the temptable and 34 in the desired table schema with unique auto id column. Using _SELECT NULL,* FROM TempTable_ saved me so much time in not having to write 34 columns

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column with the primary keys in your text file, then import it.
Note: If you get that error on the first column, make sure your file does not have the BOM. If it has the BOM (3 bytes at the beginning of the file), it will fail on the first row.

1: INSERT failed: datatype mismatch

```
>     drop table words ;
>     CREATE TABLE words (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name COLLATE NOCASE, rank INT);
>     .import file.txt words

1|a|0
2|b|0
3|c|0
4|d|0
5|e|0
6|f|0
7|g|0
```