# Import CSV into SQLite3 Using Column Subset

Tags: sql, csv, sqlite

I have a csv file that I want to import into a table. The first column of this table is a autoincrement primary key and so I want to insert the values in the csv into all the columns besides this one.

Is there a way to do this using `import` or do I need to create a temporary table and then copy these values over? ( as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994231/import-csv-into-sqlite-with-autoincrementing-primary-key?rq=1) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the value you're inserting into an autoincrement column with `NULL` and it will increment. Unfortunately, there's no way to `import` `NULL`s in *SQLite*, so you will have to resort to some kind of workaround, either what you suggest or a little script.

Comment: I opted for a simple Python script in the end.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. That's probably what I would've done too: it seems like the path of least resistance.