# sqlite: How to import a csv files into table if number of columns are not equal?

Tags: import, sqlite

I have a table in an sqlite-database which is empty and the first column of the table is autoincrement primary key. I would like to import a csv-file which has no id that is: it has as many columns as the table but one (id). How can I import the values in the csv-file into the corresponding columns of the table?

Here is a mimimal example (Windows 7, DOS):

```
REM -- Create csv-file
type NUL > data.csv
echo 'a1','b1' >> data.csv
echo 'a2','b2' >> data.csv
type data.csv
'a1','b1'
'a2','b2'

REM -- create database and tables
sqlite3 test.db "SELECT 1;"
sqlite3 test.db "CREATE TABLE tab0 (va TEXT, vb TEXT);"
REM this table has 3 columns:
sqlite3 test.db "CREATE TABLE tab1 (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, va TEXT, vb TEXT);"

REM -- Import csv file where number of columns are equal
sqlite3 -separator "," test.db ".import 'data.csv' tab0"
sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> select * from tab0;
'a1'|'b1'
'a2'|'b2'

REM -- Import csv file where number of columns are NOT equal
sqlite3 -separator "," test.db ".import 'data.csv' tab1"
data.csv:1: expected 3 columns bit found  - filling the rest with NULL
data.csv:1: INSERT failes: datatype mismatch
data.csv:2: expected 3 columns bit found  - filling the rest with NULL
data.csv:2: INSERT failes: datatype mismatch
```

Any help appreciated.

Update: Is there a way to avoid a temporary table?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the tab0 to fill tab1.

something like

```
INSERT INTO tab1( va,vb )
SELECT  va, vb
FROM    tab0
```

should work.

Comment: It works. Thanks. My workaround is using a temporary table but I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the autoincrement field to the end of the table where the missing value will be substituted by null on import and thus replaced by the autoincrement value ("NOT NULL" is implied, so you don't need it):

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (va TEXT, vb TEXT, id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
```

Comment: Thanks, I learnt something new. But obviously, there is no way to control the columns so that primary key remains on the first column.

Comment: What do you mean? You can't create or change the table in the database?

Comment: In this case I could change table but I wanted to know if there was a way if the structure of the table is given and the order of the columns in the csv-file does not accord to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Use Tab0 as temporary table from which you should insert into tab1.

```
INSERT INTO tab1(va, vb) SELECT * FROM tab0;
```

Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15998236/2591314

Comment: Thanks. Currently I use this workaround. I'm curious if there is possible to avoid this temporary table.